# Latex class deployment

Tags: package-writing

I have several `*.cls` files that serve as a template for our company documents.  It will create titlepages, copyright notices, add company logos to standard-formatted headers/footers, etc.  How can I package my `cls` files and image resources so authors have more flexibility in their `*.tex` file locations.

Currently everything is deployed in a version-control-system in a flat filestructure.  i.e.  Our 25 classes, and thousands of `tex` documents are in one directory.  This is because we need the `*.cls` files to be in the same directory as the `*.tex` files to be able to `pdflatex` them.

It's getting unmaintainable.

Instead, I'd like to deploy my `*.cls` files in a Debian package system-wide, so authors can create their own projects with their own `*.tex` files in a location of their choosing.   Then, they `\documentclass{servicebulletin}` or `\documentclass{testmanual}` in the same way they would do this with the default `article`, `report`, or `book` classes.

Is this as simple as making a Debian package which deploys my classes to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/`?

Comment: you certainly shouldn't put something into latex/base, that is for latex itself. Use a folder like tex/latex/mycompany. And normally local packages should better go into texmf-local and not into texmf-dist, or add them as their own tree with `tlmgr conf auxtrees` (if your user can use tlmgr).

Comment: This is exactly the info I'm looking for.  What are the search paths?  Would my users need to do anything to make latex search in `texmf-dist/tex/latex/mycompany` or `texmf-local/tex/latex/mycompany`?

Comment: texmf-dist need a call of `mktexlsr`, texmf-local perhaps too, not sure, I typically use dedicated texmf-trees.

Comment: Great.  I'm getting close.  I put a class in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mycompany/` and ran `sudo mktexlsr` and generated the document!  But I'm having trouble with `texmf-local`.  I've created `tex/latex/mycompany/*.cls` and put it in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local`, `/usr/share/texmf-local`, `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`, then run `sudo mktexlsr <dir>` on each directory to no avail. How can I find the location of [`TEXMFLOCAL`](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-110002.3) or define my own `texmf-*` location?

Comment: On windows I can do `kpsewhich --expand-var $texmflocal` and get back the path.  See `kpsewhich --help`. And if I want to add a new tree I use `tlmgr conf auxtrees add ...` see the docu of tlmgr.

Comment: Good to know how you do this.  `tlmgr` on Debian only runs in "user mode" to avoid conflicts with the debian package manager (`apt`, `apt-get`).  But it appears to be able to write to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf.cnf` when run with `sudo`. I think I have enough to get things working.  Will post an answer when complete.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Create your texmf tree

`*.cls` files and other resources should be in a `texmf` tree. This is a tree with `tex/latex/*.cls` or `tex/latex/<anysubdir>/*.cls`

That tree can be in a few places.  Below is where they are on debian-based distributions.  Use `kpsewhich -var-value <variable>` to find out where they are on your installation.

- `TEXMFHOME` (`$HOME/texmf`) is for a user-specific tree.  That's not appropriate when deploying a package that is system-wide.
- `TEXMFLOCAL` (`/usr/local/share/texmf`) is for a system-wide local tree.  These are typically installed by the user using something other than a package manager (such as `make install` or `git clone`).  This is also not appropriate if you're using a package manager.
- `TEXMFDIST` (`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist`) is the texlive distribution.  While you could deploy files in here, it would be best if you kept your stuff away from the official distribution to avoid polluting it.
- `TEXMFAUXTREES` (`{}`).  This is a list of additional trees that latex will use to find files.  This is perfect!

Deploy your class to some path.  Here is an appropriate path for a package:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-mycompany/tex/latex/companytemplate.cls
```

Now we need to tell latex where to look for it.

---

#### Non-Debian instructions

You can use `tlmgr` to add the auxtree (you may need `sudo`):

```
tlmgr conf auxtrees add /usr/share/texlive/texmf-mycompany
```

Confirm it was added with:

```
$ tlmgr conf auxtrees
List of auxiliary texmf trees:
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-mycompany
$ cat /usr/share/texlive/texmf.cnf 
TEXMFAUXTREES = /usr/share/texlive/texmf-mycompany,
```

#### Debian-specific instructions

`tlmgr` can conflict with `apt` or `apt-get`.  Therefore `tlmgr` is limited to user-only mode and global effects are not respected.  Instead, we need to deploy `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/01mycompany.cnf`.  The filename doesn't matter: as long as it is in that directory and ends in `.cnf`.  It should contain this content:

```
TEXMFAUXTREES = /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,
```

Then in `postinst`, run `update-texmf`.  This will concatenate all files in `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/` and generate `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` which IS used by texlive.

---

#### Confirm everything works:

```
$ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFAUXTREES
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-mycompany,      <-- You need to see your path here
                                             that means it will be searched
$ kpsewhich myclass.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-mycompany/tex/latex/myclass.cls
```

If these don't work for you, then you can troubleshoot by looking at the `*.cnf` files which are loaded and where they can be found:

```
$ kpsewhich -all texmf.cnf
/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf

$ kpsewhich -show-path texmf.cnf
/etc/texmf/web2c:/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c
```

Comment: Small bug if you are adding `texmf` trees from different packages:  Only the first definition of `TEXMFAUXTREES = ` is used by `update-texmf`.  That's not a problem for my use case, but someone may care to edit in the future to make this more friendly.